# Cell.Style.Fill.BackgroundColor doesn't read all colors

Tags: c#-4.0

I tried to read Excel sheet cells Background Colors using "Cell.Style.Fill.BackgroundColor". However, I have encountered an issue where i am only able to read a limited number(2 or 3) of colors instead of all the colors presented in the sheet[Sample excel sheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OoJe6.png)

will be appreciated for any help